# Hw to write a new field text XML attribute using Python?

Tags: python, xml, attributes

I have an XML like this:

```
<process>
     <NAME source="hsfg" class="hshah" property="Name">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </NAME>
     <number source="fdsg" class="hgdgf" property="gagfa">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </number>
     <id source="ag" class="gfdg" property="fadg">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </id>
</process>
```

I would like to add the text in here `<VALUE type="string"></VALUE>`
I tried here but it add to all the VALUE not only in the attribute this  `<NAME source="hsfg" class="hshah" property="Name">`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('Example.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in tree.iter('VALUE'):
    elem.text = 'new value'

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('newitems.xml')
```

My expectation output like this:

```
<process>
     <NAME source="hsfg" class="hshah" property="Name">
          <VALUE type="string">new value</VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </NAME>
     <number source="hsfg" class="hgdgf" property="gagfa">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </number>
     <id source="hsfg" class="gfdg" property="fadg">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </id>
</process>
```

anyone can help, please. really thankful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<process>
     <NAME source="hsfg" class="hshah" property="Name">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </NAME>
     <number source="fdsg" class="hgdgf" property="gagfa">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </number>
     <id source="ag" class="gfdg" property="fadg">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </id>
</process>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
to_change_parent = root.find('.//NAME[@source="hsfg"]')
to_change = to_change_parent.find('VALUE[@type="string"]')
to_change.text = 'new_value'
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<process>
     <NAME source="hsfg" class="hshah" property="Name">
          <VALUE type="string">new_value</VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None" />
     </NAME>
     <number source="fdsg" class="hgdgf" property="gagfa">
          <VALUE type="string" />
          <VALUE type="None" />
     </number>
     <id source="ag" class="gfdg" property="fadg">
          <VALUE type="string" />
          <VALUE type="None" />
     </id>
</process>
```

Comment: hi @balderman Thank you. Sorry I edited my xml, the value of `source` are the same.
Could you please help me to handle it? Thanks

Comment: So use the class which is not the same. See the code.

Comment: yeah, I did it. Thank you @balderman
I posted my another question here based on your answer. Please check it out if you don't mind. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/q/66666821/11076819