# Python how to keep the XML comment exist after write a new value using Python?

Tags: python, xml, comments

I have an XML file then need to update some value. My XML file contains the comment. I would like to keep the comment after writing the XML, but it disappeared.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Data System -->
<process>
     <!-- Student Name -->
     <NAME source="hsfg" class="hshah" property="Name">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </NAME>
     <!-- Exercise Number -->
     <number source="hsfg" class="hgdgf" property="gagfa">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </number>
     <!-- Exam ID -->
     <id source="hsfg" class="gfdg" property="fadg">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </id>
</process>
```

This is the value that I need to update

```
<!-- Student Name -->
     <NAME source="hsfg" class="hshah" property="Name">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </NAME>
```

become this:

```
<!-- Student Name -->
     <NAME source="hsfg" class="hshah" property="Name">
          <VALUE type="string">new value</VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </NAME>
```

My code:

```
read = ET.parse('test.xml').getroot()
parent = read.find('.//NAME[@property="Name"]')
change = parent.find('VALUE[@type="string"]')
change.text = 'new value'
tree = ET.ElementTree(read)
tree.write("test.xml")
```

The output of the test.xml file become this. the comment and `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` dissapeared.

```
<process>
     
     <NAME source="hsfg" class="hshah" property="Name">
          <VALUE type="string">new value</VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None" />
     </NAME>
     
     <number source="hsfg" class="hgdgf" property="gagfa">
          <VALUE type="string" />
          <VALUE type="None" />
     </number>
     
     <id source="hsfg" class="gfdg" property="fadg">
          <VALUE type="string" />
          <VALUE type="None" />
     </id>
</process>
```

BUT my expectation output, the structure and the comment still the same as before update the value like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Data System -->
<process>
     <!-- Student Name -->
     <NAME source="hsfg" class="hshah" property="Name">
          <VALUE type="string">new value</VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </NAME>
     <!-- Exercise Number -->
     <number source="hsfg" class="hgdgf" property="gagfa">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </number>
     <!-- Exam ID -->
     <id source="hsfg" class="gfdg" property="fadg">
          <VALUE type="string"></VALUE>
          <VALUE type="None"></VALUE>
     </id>
</process>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `ET.XMLParser` to preserve comments
2. Use `encoding` and `xml_declaration` arguments in `write()` function to write xml declaration
   Try the following code:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
parser = ET.XMLParser(target=ET.TreeBuilder(insert_comments=True))

read = ET.parse('newXml.xml', parser=parser).getroot()
parent = read.find('.//NAME[@property="Name"]')
change = parent.find('VALUE[@type="string"]')
change.text = 'new value'
tree = ET.ElementTree(read)
tree.write("test.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

you can also avoid variable `read` and just use `tree`:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
parser = ET.XMLParser(target=ET.TreeBuilder(insert_comments=True))

tree = ET.parse('newXml.xml', parser=parser)
parent = tree.find('.//NAME[@property="Name"]')
change = parent.find('VALUE[@type="string"]')
change.text = 'new value'
tree.write("test.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```